# respond_to?() from top level of script

Tags: ruby

I can use respond_to?() from the main object in `irb`:

```
irb(main):001:0> def foo
irb(main):002:1>   "hi"
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> respond_to?(:foo)
=> true
irb(main):005:0> self
=> main
```

But when I put this into a script, it doesn't seem work as I'd expect:

```
$ cat test.rb
#! /usr/local/bin/ruby
def foo
  "hi"
end
puts respond_to?(:foo)
puts self

$ ./test.rb
false
main
```

What's going on here?

EDIT:

The `irb` behavior works for me in 1.9.3, but not in 2.2.0.  But regardless, is it possible to use respond_to?() as such from a script?

As an alternative, I can catch a `NoMethodError` from a call to `send()`, but that would also catch such exceptions from inside a valid method as well, which makes error handling a little convoluted.

Comment: In `irb`, I get the same result as a script (outputs `false` at the first `puts`)... but my terminal doesn't show `irb(main)`, just `irb`... ?

Comment: Nope, `irb` shows `main` at start up for me.

Comment: Different ruby versions? add `puts RUBY_VERSION` ...? You leave me clueless...

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: `irb` inconsistency aside, I'd like this to work in the script.  Not possible?

Comment: What's your aversion to using classes and proper OO design?

Comment: I'm fine with wrapping the script's work in a class, but I'm just curious as to why it doesn't work from the top level context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods defined at the top level are made private methods of `Object` and by default [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) only returns true for public methods.  To check for private and protected methods, set the `include_all` argument to true:

```
def foo
  "hi"
end 

puts respond_to?(:foo, true)
puts self
```

Now when the script is run, `respond_to?(:foo, true)` should return true:

```
$ ./test.rb
true
main
```